# Matlab error: Undefined function 'imhist', but Image Processing Toolbox is installed

Tags: matlab, image-processing, undefined

I'm trying to use the SHINE toolbox to control for contrast/luminance across a set of images and the toolbox requires Matlab's Image Processing Toolbox.

I've checked (using ver and also through the Set Path option on the GUI) that the toolbox is indeed installed and on my path. ('/Applications/MATLAB_R2016b.app/toolbox/images')

Yet I still get the error `Undefined function 'imhist' for input arguments of type 'uint8'.`

Any ideas for why it's still failing to call IPT functions?

Comment: How do you check for the toolbox and what result you get? How are you using the function `imhist`?

Comment: Type `which imhist -all` in the Command Window. Does it list more than one file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience, this problem occurred when the function is not in your toolbox or your directory. Check if your toolbox is installed, write

```
which imhist
```

if it's returning a path. If it's not, maybe its because your matlab license. The other solution that I can reccomend is copy the 'imhist' function to your current project so it will run with your current project.

Comment: Yep, it seems the cause was that simple -- didn't realize I didn't have a license for that particular toolbox. Thanks!